# Build failed Windows error (docker) of project (https://github.com/TencentCloud/O266player.git)

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, dockerfile, vlc

I just downloaded master.zip of GitHub, I just tried to build the given Dockerfile:
`docker build -t o266player --force-rm .`

Here is what I got an error:

```
[+] Building 3.7s (11/16)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                                                                             3.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 44B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:626ffe58f6e7566e00254b638eb7e0f3b11d4da9675088f4781a50ae288f3322                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/12] RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common   && add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --n  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/12] RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/TencentCloud/O266player.git                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/12] RUN cd /O266player/extras/tools   && ./bootstrap   && make .protoc                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/12] RUN mkdir -p O266player/contrib/win32   && cd O266player/contrib/win32   && ../bootstrap --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32   && make fetch                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/12] ADD o266dec-win64.tar.xz /                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [ 7/12] RUN cd o266dec-win64   && ./install.sh   && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix   && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  0.4s
------
 > [ 7/12] RUN cd o266dec-win64   && ./install.sh   && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix   && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix:
#11 0.376 container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd o266dec-win64   && ./install.sh   && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix   && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix]: exit code: 1
```

Is there anything else to solve this? I'm not good programmer.
I'm currently running Docker Desktop on Windows 11.

Comment: Did you follow explicitly what is mentioned in the README.md? "Rename the decoder package to `o266dec-win64.tar.tz`, and put it in the same folder as the downloaded Dockerfile. No need to uncompress it."

Comment: yeah, but I tried and it says ERROR [ 6/12] ADD o266dec-win64.tar.xz / so I renamed back to tar.xz, also dockerfile I edited: # install O266 decoder
ADD o266dec-win64.tar.xz /
RUN cd o266dec-win64 \
  && ./install.sh \
  && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix \
  && update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix, I think install.sh is missing